# Failed to install phablet-tools

Tags: apt, software-installation

I have done all these

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phablet-team/tools
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install phablet-tools android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```

its 12.04 LTS i think...

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do a `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get upgrade` and then `sudo apt-get install -f`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is telling you that the packages are already installed, but it has not installed all of the other packages it needs to work. You should be able to solve this by running this:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

<sup>*(This command should automatically install the unmet dependencies.)*</sup>

or this:

```
sudo apt-get install click curl dpkg-dev python-lzma python-requests imagemagick ubuntu-dev-tools
```

If some of those packages are not available, you can search for ways to install them [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/) or [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/).

Comment: package click has no installation candidate

Comment: http://prntscr.com/2x58fv

Comment: In that case you search for it, and find [this](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/ubuntu_sdk_release/precise/main/base/click), and install the .deb package, or add [this PPA](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/ubuntu_sdk_release?dist=precise).

Comment: Thank you very much Wilf - Still discovering ubuntu secrets :D

Comment: Your welcome - ubuntu probably needs a better package manager anyway :-)